# Installing soda cli in existing app golang

Tags: go

### Description

Issue while installing soda cli in existing app
I downloaded the cli like the documentation
https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/db/toolbox

#### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

$ go get github.com/gobuffalo/pop/...
$ go install github.com/gobuffalo/pop/soda

#### Expected Behavior

when i write soda -v
it must show soda version

#### Actual Behavior

soda: command not found

#### Info

OS: ubuntu 21

Answer (score 2):

The problem is very probably that the path where the `soda` binary gets installed is not in your `PATH` system variable.

To know where your go binaries are installed, run:

```
go env | grep GOPATH
```

This will print:

```
GOPATH="/path/to/go"
```

Then you need to add `/path/to/go/bin` in your environment, through your `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `.profile` or whatever you need to have it in your environment, adding the line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/go/bin"
```

You can do all of this in one single command:

```
echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:${$(go env | grep GOPATH | cut -d '=' -f2):1:-1}/bin\"" >> .bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

If soda is installed inside go/bin

Just add an alias for soda

Open your terminal and write this command

```
alias soda="~/go/bin/soda"
```

To write permanent alias

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

And in the end of file write the alias

```
alias soda="~/go/bin/soda"
```